# How to export file and running app

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create 2 seperate files in my app,
one for API request, and second one for socket.io
The starting file is `app.js` which look like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
   res.send('test');
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
}); 

module.exports = app;
```

and the second file for socket.io looks like this:

```
const app = require('./app');
const http = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);

...

http.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('listening on *: ',port);
});
```

When I run the app with my IDE (VSCODE) everything works perfect, 
but when I'm trying to run on the terminal the app doesn't start and the page isn't available on the starting port.

I think that the problem is about the export for the socketIO file in app.js,

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it were a problem with the export then the app would most likely crash on start up in both scenarios, more likely a path issue - when running from the terminal does the app start at all? Or is there an error? Really not much to go on here...

Comment: Also, FWIW you are unnecessarily duplicating the `/` route in the socket file.

Comment: When I run from terminal it says: 
> testsocketio@1.0.0 start C:\Users\abc\PhpstormProjects\SocketIO\socket_test2
> node app.js
nothing more

Comment: @James I edited the question, no duplicate this time

Comment: Think the issue is your using `http` *and* express as it seems to be hanging. Try just `app.listen`.

Comment: still doesn't work, and if I move app.listen to app.js the app doesn't load even when I starting it from the IDE

Comment: Hmm can't really see anything obvious wrong. Although, I'd recommend just moving your app into the main file and moving your route config into their own files instead (making use of express.Router). To reiterate though, you should use `app.listen` over `http`, I'm sure Express uses `http` internally. I recommend moving everything into a single file to narrow the problem down.